# Copy-Item and rename to a specific parent directory in Powershell

Tags: database, powershell, batch-file

I've got a script that will copy a list of directories that I've filtered and copied into a new directory with the name plus the LastWriteTime

```
$srcdir = "Z:\Production500\000600"
$destdir = "X:\Standards\Water Resources\GIS\_Water Resources GIS Database\_Unprocessed_Raw_data"
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "Z:\Production500\000600" -Filter "Water Resources","GIS" -Recurse
$i=1
$folders | % ($_) {cp $_.FullName -Destination "$destdir\$($_.Name + $_.LastWriteTime.toString("_yyyy_MM_dd_") + $i)" -recurse; $i++}
```

The script works great copying the exact folders and files I need into the following format:

```
.\GIS_2017_07_09_1
.\GIS_2017_07_10_2
.\GIS_2017_07_10_3
```

Instead of the counter, I'd prefer to have a name on the end from one of the parent directories. For Example if $folders is this list:

```
 Directory: Z:\Production500\000600\B000676\Design\004\Chisholm Park\Water Resources
 Directory: Z:\Production500\000600\B000667\Design\001\Water Resources
 Directory: Z:\Production500\000600\B000663\Design\001\Water Resources
```

I'd like the copied items renamed to this:

```
.\GIS_2017_07_09_B000676
.\GIS_2017_07_10_B000667
.\GIS_2017_07_10_B000663
```

thus eliminating the need for the counter and also making the destination more organized. Notably, the B000### is always the 3rd folder deep.

Comment: you do not need two times get-childitem. You can use comma separated values. use like this `Get-ChildItem  "Z:\Production500\000600" -Filter "Water Resources","GIS" -Recurse
`

Comment: Are you sure that you want to pick the 3rd level folder name only?

Comment: Yes, its always the 3rd. @Ranadip-Dutta. And thanks for the tip on the filter switch!

Comment: On which path the parent folder name is mentioned? will it be in the $destination or in $source

Comment: @RanadipDutta It will be the source. The parent folder will also be in the list of $folders since it needs to loop and copy and rename each one from that list into the format above.

Comment: I have added the answer. Change the placeholders accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your path is mentioned in  a variable and you can proceed with this since you have already mentioned that it will always be the 3rd level folder:

You can use the spilt to get the folder name and can put it inside the foreach

```
$path="Z:\Production500\000600\B000676\Design\004\Chisholm Park\Water Resources"

$srcdir = "Z:\Production500\000600"
$destdir = "X:\Standards\Water Resources\GIS\_Water Resources GIS Database\_Unprocessed_Raw_data"
$folders = Get-ChildItem "Z:\Production500\000600" -Filter "Water Resources","GIS" -Recurse
$folders | % ($_) {cp $_.FullName -Destination "$destdir\$($_.Name + $_.LastWriteTime.toString("_yyyy_MM_dd_") + "$($path.split('\')[3])")" -recurse}
```

You do not need the *$i* variable and do not need to do the incremental operation.

Make sure you are giving the path properly so that it can split on each path. This is just a sample hardcoding the path since you have not specified whether it will be in the destination path or the source path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!! Ranadip

Comment: Not a problem @KevinG. Enjoy Coding